# evento para controlar el dobleClick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

He logrado realizar una función en el primer click

```js
function s(){
      $('div').addClass('s');
      $('div').css({display:"block"});
      console.log("click");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="s()">Haz Click!</button>
```

Pero no se como detectar el segundo click

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con `evento segundo click`?

Comment: si quieres que al hacer el priner click haga algo y luego del doble click otra cosa , es dificil debes tener un contador ahora si es doble click puedes hacerlo con una funcion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

puedes establecer una variable `clics` y de ahí poder determinar cuantos clics va realizando el usuario sobre ese botón

```
var clics = 0;
function s() {
    if(clics == 0) {
       //primer clic
    }
    else {
        //segundo clic
    }
    ++clics;
}
```

Comment: el problema de esta respuesta es que para saber el segundo click es cuestion de milisegundos, el contador te mantendra el valor indiferentemente cuando haga click, por eso javascript creo el dblclick

Answer (score 0):

Para un evento doble click puedes utilizar esto:

```
$( "#target" ).dblclick(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .dblclick() called." );
});
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

los listenner tienen una funcion llamada [`dblclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondblclick) , un ejemplo usando click y doble click, debes tener cuidado con esto te recomiendo usar una u otra para evitar confusiones

```js
miDobleClick.addEventListener("dblclick" , function(){
console.info("chispas doble click")
})
miDobleClick.addEventListener("click" , function(){
console.log("mantengo mi click")
})
```

```html
<button id="miDobleClick">Haz Click!</button>
```